# Go: Act on Signal while not Blocking Operations

Tags: go

I want to fire the `ps` command continuously in a goroutine to monitor mem and cpu usages.  I didn't use `top` because `top` doesn't allow me to select columns as `ps` does.  This goroutine needs to receive a stop signal to stop the `command`, but I don't know how not to block running the command while waiting the signal. For `top` I can do:

```
top := exec.Command("top")
<-stop // blocking
top.Process.Signal(os.Kill)
```

But for `ps` if I do:

```
ps := exec.Command("ps")
for {
    ps.Run()
    <-stop
}
```

The above code will block on `stop`. I want to keep firing `ps.Run()`, while being able to stop when a stop signal is ready.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that you could achieve this is by utilizing the for/select timeout  idiom, there are a couple of similar methods of doing this. Take this trivial example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    abort := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-abort:
                return
            case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
                // replace fmt.Println() with the command you wish to run
                fmt.Println("tick")
            }
        }
    }()
    // replace time.Sleep() with code waiting for 'abort' command input
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    abort <- struct{}{}
}
```

To modify this example to work in your circumstance place the code that you want to run in the `<-time.After():` case, which (in this instance) will run once per second, if no other case is available to receive for that duration. And instead of `time.Sleep()` which I placed at the end, put the code that will interrupt the  `<-time.After():` case, sending `<- struct{}{}` on the `abort` channel (or whatever you name it).

NOTE: In an earlier version of this answer I had abort as a `chan bool`, as I like the clarity of `<-abort true` and don't consider  `chan struct{}` to be as clear, I opted to change it in this example however, as `<- struct{}{}` isn't unclear, especially once you've gotten used to the pattern.

Also, if you want the command to execute on each iteration of the for loop and not wait for a timeout then you can make that case `default:`, remove `<-time.After()` and it will run on each iteration of the loop where another channel is not ready to receive.

You can play with this example in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8R3FElLtI-) if you'd like, although it will not allow syscalls, or the `default:` case example to be run in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

To run it over and over, without sleep:

```
func run(stop <-chan struct{}) {
    ps := exec.Command("ps")
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            return
        default:
            ps.Run()
            //processing the output
        }
    }
}
```

And then `go run(stop)`. And to run it every 3 seconds (for example):

```
func run(stop <-chan struct{}) {
    ps := exec.Command("ps")
    tk := time.Tick(time.Second * 3)
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            return
        case <-tk:
            ps.Run()
            //processing the output
        }
    }
}
```